# React MDC Web Textfiled's helptext with html string

Tags: html, reactjs, material-design, materialize, material-ui

I am using [`Textfiled`](https://react-mdc.github.io/#/textfield) component in **`React Material Component`** with an `html string` as `help text` getting following `warning` in the browser console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `helptext` of type `object` supplied to `t`, expected `string`.
    in t (created by DetailsForm)
    in DetailsForm (created by Unknown)
    in div (created by Unknown)
    in form (created by Unknown)
    in dialog (created by Unknown)
    in Unknown
```

This is how I am using `Textfiled` component:

```
    <Textfield
       name="bill"
       floatingLabel="Total bill"
       disabled={this.state.isDisabled}
       helptext={helpTextBill}
       helptextPersistent
       value={this.state.bill}
    />
```

Where the value of `helpTextBill` is:

```
helpTextBill = (<span>For details visit <a href="/url-path/"> here </a></span>)
```

This is just warning, but would like know how to handle and resolve this.

Comment: The proptypes specified for the `Textfield` component are there to tell you what types the properties need to be: `helptext` should be a string, not an object. That warning is there to inform you that you're giving it a property of the wrong type. Don't ignore it - your component will probably not render the way you expect it to.

Comment: @Kryten Can you suggest me how to over come this scenario?

Comment: I think I have to create a **custom component** by extending the `Material Textfield component`